# What is the purpose of and what happens during "memory training"?

Tags: memory

I was watching this [Jayz's Two Cent's video](https://youtu.be/H5AM7yhvsPU?t=142), and he mentions "memory training"... what is that? From my understanding the BIOS persists the timings and voltages and clock settings in CMOS, so what is being discovered by the "training"? Is it just a warm-up?

Comment: That's a really bad computer term, not worth 2 cents, what he is doing is resetting nvram which forces the bios to detect the new ram, more like bios training. Anyone can make a video, does not mean they know what they are talking about.

Comment: But if you already have the values stored in CMOS what is being detected/trained? Are there other values other than timings/voltage/clock speed that the BIOS stores that are not exposed in BIOS?

Comment: Its different memory, different cas latency most likely, it could be any minor difference.